# Truth Tables Using XS-3

Tags: logic

I was asked to build truth tables using XS-3 and I wanted to know how I refer to a situation in which the output is not set, for example, for 1110 I will not get anything.
Little explanation $0000 = 0 => 0+3 = 3 => 0011$ this is the meaning of XS-3.

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excess-3)

Thanks!

Comment: Wikipedia explanation is that up to 12 but what do you do with the rest of the numbers? This method is the  to 4 bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excess-3 is defined *strictly* on the domain ranging from decimal $-3$ to $12$ for *four bits*.  That's where it's defined for four bits. It's output ranges from $0000$ to $1111$. $1111$ is the output for an input value of decimal $12$, so the largest defined input on four bits is $1100$.

So if you're adding $0011=3_{10}$ to a four-bit number, $1110 = $ decimal $14$, you'll have a carry, $(1)0001,$ i.e. "overflow"...when you're limited to four bits. I.e. XS-3 is **not defined** on $N = 4$ bits. If you had five bits (*which you don't*), XS-3 of $1110$ would be $10001$.

I.e. $1110$ is "out of the domain of definition" on four-bits: $\operatorname{XS-3}(1110)$ is not defined on four bits.

Comment: also deserves a thumbs - up! +1